# Are there any potential issues with using `if(count($_POST) > 0)` to check if any data has been POSTed in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, post

I was looking for a catch-all way to easily determine whether any user data was posted via any HTML Form -- without having to worry about the intricacies of each individual Form -- in order to easily prohibit unregistered users from posting any content on the site.

Assuming the Form's `action` attribute is always `POST`, is there any potential issues with using:

`if(count($_POST) > 0)`

to check if any data was posted?

In other words, is there any scenario where `count($_POST)` might be `> 0` even if the user **did not** submit any info via `POST`, or where `count($_POST)` might `== 0` even if the user **did** submit any info via `POST`?

(I first tried `isset($_POST)`, but that didn't work as it returns `true` even if no `POST` data is submitted by the user.)

Comment: It's self-explanatory. `(count($_POST)` reads the number of post submissions. If there are none, `(count($_POST)` will always be 0

Comment: I usually use something like if(isset($_POST['my_field'])) so that not only do I know if the data was posted, but also that the data I expected was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the simplest way to determine if one or more values have been sent via POST.

```
if ($_POST) {
    // it is 100% reliably implied that count($_POST) > 0
}
```

However, sometimes you may receive a form post that doesn't contain any keys/values. An example would be an "accept our terms of service by clicking the checkbox" type form, where the only form field is a checkbox, or submit button. Checkbox name/value pairs are only sent if the checkbox gets checked, and submit buttons name/values aren't always sent by browsers. Another example where $_POST could have no entries could be a file upload form. A good form handler will properly behave in these scenarios. You can use the following to detect a post request in ALL circumstances.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // its a post request, although we may have 0 posted values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `empty($_POST)`, checks for isset and null / blank values. But as $_POST will always be set you will be mainly checking if it is blank or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a little weird that you would not have an expectation of what is coming to a page of your own making, but no there is not any problem with that.

The reason `isset($_POST)` does not work as it is always set (it is superglobal).

Comment: I find that it is good practice to check that the data is being sent, in case a user were to try and visit login.php directly, that way I can provide a redirect to the proper page, or an intelligent error message.

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 Umm, if a username and password are not supplied, why would your code not just send them back to the login screen with an error message without doing this? To each his own, but seems like a pretty rare situation to be coding for on every single page where you are expecting data.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Perhaps login.php was a bad example, as you are right, but any php file that is only for processing data, I like to check that the data was actually sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned about data posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (i.e. from typical forms) then `count` or `empty` should be sufficient to check.

If you are looking for for ANY kind of raw data POST input you should use:

```
if(empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))) {
   // there is no POST data
}
```

I should add that it is probably not that useful to actually check if no data was posted at all except for the case where you are dealing with raw POST data (i.e. `application/json` or some similar non-form requests).  Usually, you are only interested in the SPECIFIC data the handling script expects.  So this is in essence useless code, since you still need to check for the presence of that specific data (i.e. `empty($_POST['some_field'])`).

Answer (score 0):

If all your forms are identical and there aren't any special or strange requests coming from other servers, `count()` should work just fine.